# Old connection are not terminated upon connecting to a VPN

Tags: vpn, routing, openvpn

I have been testing my OpenVPN server for leaking on Windows 10. I logged packets with Wireshark and generated traffic by reloading [this](http://www.whatsmyip.org/random-website-machine/random/) in Firefox every 10 seconds.

- In my first try, I started reloading that page, connected to the VPN
  and started capturing with Wireshark. Among about 150000 captured
  packets, there are still some plain HTTP requests (the last one was
  at about 10000th position). Those HTTP connections are either to
  Google, Cloudfront or Mozilla.
- In my second try, I connected to the VPN first, then started 
  reloading that page and capturing with Wireshark. This time there was
  no HTTP connection observed.

My question is: if those connections were opened since before I initialized the VPN, why didn't they get terminated once I connected to the VPN. Or at least if they were still kept alive, they should be routed through the VPN as there were new route added to the route table. Was there any effect of caching here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connecting to a VPN only changes the routing table -
the VPN server will tell the client that it is to be the default gateway.
This means that all **future** connections will pass through the VPN.

However, **existing** connections are not closed and remain connected.
They cannot be moved to the VPN without disconnection, so they remain outside
the VPN.

That said, it is strange that any add-on will keep an open connection
for any length of time,
as they should rather reconnect periodically.
I find this somewhat suspicious.

You could use a product such as [TCPView](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437)
to keep an eye on the connections and to which IP address they connect.
Use a Whois service on that IP address to find out to which server they connect.
This might help locate the add-on that is responsible for these connections,
to decide if it is legit.